# How to use components for an href in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, href

I want to use a component as an href in an a tag.
This is my code

```
<template>
    <a v-bind:href="Library">  </a>
</template>

<script>
import Library from './Library';

export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        Library,
    },
}
</script>

<style>
    
</style>
```

Unfortunately, I get an error saying I didn't use the library component.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Kind regards
Emiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a component as a string

try this ([example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdD5cbmltcG9ydCBMaWJyYXJ5IGZyb20gJy4vTGlicmFyeS5qcydcbiAgZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQge1xuICAgIGRhdGEoKSB7XG4gICAgICByZXR1cm4ge1xuICAgICAgICBMaWJyYXJ5OiBMaWJyYXJ5XG4gICAgICB9XG4gICAgfVxufVxuPC9zY3JpcHQ+XG5cbjx0ZW1wbGF0ZT5cbiAgPGEgOmhyZWY9XCJMaWJyYXJ5XCIgdGFyZ2V0PVwiX2JsYW5rXCI+dGVzdDwvYT5cbjwvdGVtcGxhdGU+IiwiaW1wb3J0LW1hcC5qc29uIjoie1xuICBcImltcG9ydHNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwidnVlXCI6IFwiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZmMudnVlanMub3JnL3Z1ZS5ydW50aW1lLmVzbS1icm93c2VyLmpzXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsIkxpYnJhcnkuanMiOiJjb25zdCBMaWJyYXJ5ID0gXCJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZS5jb21cIjtcbmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IExpYnJhcnlcbiJ9))

```js
<script>
import Library from './Library.js'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        Library: Library
      }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
  <a :href="Library" target="_blank">test</a>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried it, the error is gone, but I don't get sent to the library.vue file

Comment: Ohh, thats a very different question. You need something like [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) to make that.

Comment: oh ok alright, do you know how to implement this in my code fastly or do I just have to learn this myself

Comment: There is no fast way :/ Vue router requires some reading and understanding. But it will be worth it! You will definitely use it a lot in the future! [This page](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html) should get you started in a few hours.